# About mitigating circumstance

Tags: working-visas, immigration, student-visa

I am a Tier 4 student. Doing my masters in one of the Universities in UK. Recently I failed to attend one of the written exams. I need submit mitigating form. I submitted it. I did not give any medical evidence at that time, I don't have any such reason. I was going to the wrong venue. I did not get any email alerts about the change of venue. I believe that the exam is in the same venue, that I have attended the exam. Now they rejected the mitigation form. I need to appeal it within 5 days. But it will not give me a favorable decision, that they told.

**Due to academic issues I have been removed from the course that my visa is attached.**

Is there any chance to remain in the country.

Or Is it possible to get a Tie2 sponsorship without completing a master degree.

Already I am working in the web development field. 4 of my friends are interested to sponsor me. But without holding a master course is it possible.

How can I overcome this situation?. Any chance to change visa status.

Answer (score 1):

You can only extend your leave if you are offered a new CAS, with the current or another University, so you would be able to extend your leave if the current course provider withdraws you from the course.

To switch your leave into the Tier 2, you will need to complete your degree as this is a requirement. If you do not, then you will need to leave the UK and apply for entry clearance under the Tier 2. However this would mean the employer will have to apply for a restricted CoS.